# How do I extract a long listing field?

Tags: bash, shell, shell-script, ls, timestamps

I want to extract the access day of a file in a shell script. I tried by writing the following script but it doesn't work. When I echo *accessday*, the output is "staff".

```
file=$1
accessday=$(ls -lu $file | cut -d ' ' -f 6)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Don't parse `ls`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/128985/68757).

This is a job for `stat`.

To get the last access time in human readable format:

```
stat -c '%x' file.txt
```

in seconds since epoch:

```
stat -c '%X' file.txt
```

Comment: Why don't I parse ls ?

Comment: @OutOfBounds check http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/128985/68757

Comment: btw, your own question provides a good example of exactly why you shouldn't parse ls.  the output format is not fixed, and not reliable.

Comment: also btw, the above `stat` command works with GNU `stat`.  for FreeBSD or Mac OS X `stat`, you'd use `stat -f '%a' file.txt` (for access time in seconds since epoch) or `stat -f '%Sa' file.txt` (for access time in `strftime()` format)

Answer (score 2):

If you look at the typical output of `ls -lu`,

```
-rw-r--r--  1 someuser  somegroup  74 Mar 29 05:21 filename
```

you'll notice that a total of five space characters precedes the group name. Your specification of field 6 in the `cut` command thus returns the group ("staff" in your case).

Also, the access day would be field 7, not 6 in your notation.

One solution would be to use `awk`, since it handles multiple occurences of the field separator the way you expected by default:

```
accessday=$(ls -lu $file | awk '{print $7}')
```

Answer (score 2):

Based on your question I would use stat to normalize the output, then cut to only display the date that you wanted.

`stat -c '%x' FILENAME | cut -c 9,10`

Answer (score 2):

Parsing the output of `ls` is [difficult and not always possible](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs). If you want to extract a timestamp, it is sometimes a necessary fallback (it's the only portable way to do so: not all systems have a `stat` command), but you get a human-readable timestamp which is [hard to convert to a machine-readable one](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/271002/create-directory-named-from-file-modification-time/271067#271067). At least get the difficult parts out of the way: pass the `-o` and `-g` options to omit the user and group fields (these can contain spaces on some systems, making them impossible to delimit in the output of `ls`). Then the timestamp occupies fields 4–6 (numbering from 1).

[Don't forget double quotes around variable expansions](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/131766/why-does-my-shell-script-choke-on-whitespace-or-other-special-characters?s=2|0.6666).

```
access_time=$(ls -dlogu -- "$file" | awk '1 {print $4, $5, $6}')
```

If you want the day of the month, you need to distinguish the two output formats, for timestamps within the past 6 months or not. Set the locale to C to get a reliable output format. In this format, the day of the month is always the second timestamp field.

```
access_day=$(ls -dlogu -- "$file" | awk '1 {print $5}')
```